# Why is fusion table style not reflected in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I am importing fusion tables to google map but the icon colour used in fusion table is not reflected in my map. It was working a few days back but now something went wrong. Please can someone suggest me the reason.

```
layer1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
query: {
select: 'latitude',
from: '1f1XfTx7J52PZJv3mwnBq3rCiPwb6x1li67ca6lg'
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You must define the `styleId` via the `options`-property when you want to apply a style of a map-view in your external map:

To determine the `styleId` click on the arrow on the right side of the view-tab, then choose publish->get html and javascript.
This will give you the complete code to publish the map-view on a external page, which also contains the `styleId`.

In this case the `styleId` is `2`

```
layer1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
    select: 'latitude',
    from:   '1f1XfTx7J52PZJv3mwnBq3rCiPwb6x1li67ca6lg'
  },
  options:{
    styleId: 2
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was trying a lot but could not find a solution. But still there is a problem. My icon colours are changed but the info window details are not seen.

Comment: I can't tell you why without seeing your implemetation, maybe it's a css-issue.